# Get custom fields for all users from Slack API

Tags: python, slack-api

This is my first python attempt and i'm trying to get a custom field for all Slack users. These fields are not available from the users.list feature so I need to run a users.profile.get for each ID in the users.list response and write the results to a file.

I have managed to get this far but I need some hints/help to get further. How do i call users.profile.get for all IDs from users.list?

```
import os
import io

from slackclient import SlackClient

slack_token = os.environ["SLACK_API_TOKEN"]
sc = SlackClient(slack_token)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    api_call = sc.api_call("users.list")
    if api_call.get('ok'):
        users = api_call.get('members')
        for user in users:
                print(user['name'] + ' is : ' + user.get('id'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a for loop and the "user.info" api method.
https://api.slack.com/methods/users.info

```
for user in users:
    user_info = sc.api_call("users.info", user=user.get('id'))
    custom_field = user_info['user'][CUSTOM_FIELD]
```

api_call can be used for just about any method at https://api.slack.com/methods